# Breadth-First Search in C: Maze-like use of 2D arrays, linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, breadth-first-search

**Problem**:

> In a grid of nodes pick a starting node(has mode2), and using Breadth-First search, find one with a ending node (has mode1).

You can make walls so it's harder for the search. And that inspired me to make an algorithm which creates mazes, so my search will have something interesting to solve.

I want to know how drastically I need to change to code to fit my ideas, overall quality of the style and code itself. Did I break some essential rule in C? What can I change to make my code more readable. What parts of the code could I had written in fewer lines?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEIGHT 10
#define WIDTH 10

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define MIN(A,B) (A > B) ? B: A
#define MAX(A,B) (A < B) ? B: A

struct node {
    int mode;
    struct node *up;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *down;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *next;
}; 

typedef struct point {
    int y;
    int x;
}Point;

struct node matrix[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

//Handles the queue
struct node *ptrCurrent = NULL; //First in que
struct node *ptrLast = NULL; //Last added in que

void setupMatrix(void);
void printMatrix(void);
int bfs(void);
void makeWall(Point first, Point second);
Point makePoint(int y, int x);

int main() 
{   
    setupMatrix();

    Point begining = makePoint(4,3);
    Point destination = makePoint(4,6);

    matrix[destination.y][destination.x].mode = 1; //Destination: mode1
    matrix[begining.y][begining.x].mode = 2; //Begining: mode2

    //Walls have mode4
    makeWall(makePoint(8,5),makePoint(1,5)); 

    //Inicialise the queue from the begining node
    ptrCurrent = &matrix[begining.y][begining.x];
    ptrLast = &matrix[begining.y][begining.x];

    //Explanation of modes
    printf("Modes:\n"
    "5-FoundSolution\n"
    "4-Wall\n"
    "3-CheckedSpace\n"
    "2-Start\n"
    "1-Destination\n\n");

    //START:
    int status = bfs();

    //When finished:
    if(status) {
    printMatrix(); //Mode5 represents the found solution
    } else {
        printf("Restart the program if you wish to try again.\n");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int bfs(void) 
{   
    int tries = 0;
    if(ptrCurrent->mode == 2)
    while(1) 
    {
        ptrCurrent->mode = 3;

        if(ptrCurrent->up != NULL) 
        {
            if(ptrCurrent->up->mode == 1) 
            {
                printf("Found the solution\n");
                ptrCurrent->up->mode = 5;
                return 1;
            } 
            else if(ptrCurrent->up->mode == 0) 
            { 
                ptrCurrent->up->mode = 3; 
                ptrLast->next = ptrCurrent->up;
                ptrLast = ptrCurrent->up;
            }
        }

        if(ptrCurrent->left != NULL) 
        {
            if(ptrCurrent->left->mode == 1) 
            {
                printf("Found the solution\n");
                ptrCurrent->left->mode = 5;
                return 1;
            } 
            else if(ptrCurrent->left->mode == 0) 
            { 
                ptrCurrent->left->mode = 3; 
                ptrLast->next = ptrCurrent->left;
                ptrLast = ptrCurrent->left;
            }
        }

        if(ptrCurrent->down != NULL) 
        {
            if(ptrCurrent->down->mode == 1) 
            {
                printf("Found the solution\n");
                ptrCurrent->down->mode = 5;
                return 1;
            } else if(ptrCurrent->down->mode == 0) 
            {
                ptrCurrent->down->mode = 3;
                ptrLast->next = ptrCurrent->down;
                ptrLast = ptrCurrent->down;
            }
        }

        if(ptrCurrent->right != NULL) {
            if(ptrCurrent->right->mode == 1) 
            {
                printf("Found the solution\n");
                ptrCurrent->right->mode = 5;
                return 1;
            } 
            else if(ptrCurrent->right->mode == 0) 
            {
                ptrCurrent->right->mode = 3;
                ptrLast->next = ptrCurrent->right;
                ptrLast = ptrCurrent->right;
            }
        }
        if(ptrCurrent->next != 0)
            ptrCurrent = ptrCurrent->next;
        else {
            printf("Nowhere to go, can't reach destination.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        tries++;
        if(tries > 1000) {
            printf("Didin't found the solution after 1000 tries.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Properly set begining tile to mode2.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void setupMatrix(void) 
{
    int i,j;

    for(j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) 
    {
        for(i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) 
        {

            matrix[j][i].mode = 0;

            matrix[j][i].next = NULL;


            //Connect UP
            if(j == 0)
                matrix[j][i].up = NULL;
            else
                matrix[j][i].up = &matrix[j-1][i];

            //Connect LEFT
            if(i == 0)
                matrix[j][i].left = NULL;
            else
                matrix[j][i].left = &matrix[j][i-1];

            //Connect DOWN
            if(j == HEIGHT-1)
                matrix[j][i].down = NULL;
            else
                matrix[j][i].down = &matrix[j+1][i];

            //Connect RIGHT
            if(i == WIDTH-1)
                matrix[j][i].right = NULL;
            else
                matrix[j][i].right = &matrix[j][i+1];

        }
    }
}

void printMatrix(void) 
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) 
    {
        for(i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) 
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[j][i].mode);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void makeWall(Point first, Point second) {
    int i;
    int start,end;

    if(first.x == second.x) {
        start = MIN(first.y, second.y);
        end = MAX(first.y, second.y);
        for(i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if(matrix[i][first.x].mode != 1 && matrix[i][first.x].mode != 2)
                matrix[i][first.x].mode = 4;
            else
                printf("Can't make a wall over a destination, or begining.\n");
        }
    }
    else if(first.y == second.y) {
        start = MIN(first.x, second.x);
        end = MAX(first.x, second.x);
        for(i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if(matrix[first.y][i].mode != 1 && matrix[first.y][i].mode != 2)
                matrix[first.y][i].mode = 4;
            else
                printf("Can't make a wall over a destination, or begining.\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("You can only make walls horizontaly and verticaly.\n");
    } 
} 

Point makePoint(int y, int x) {
    Point newPoint = {y,x};
    if(y > HEIGHT || x > WIDTH || x < 0 || y < 0) {
        printf("Point not in matrix space.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    return newPoint;      
}
```

Comment: Does your code currently work to create mazes or are you looking for a solution to make it do that?

Comment: It does not create mazes, only a 2d grid, on it you can only create "walls", to hide the destination.  What maze generating algoritams work solidly and are easiy to implement? I'm gonna try Recursive backtracker.